# How to change format decimal using jquery mask input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [Jquery input mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/). I have a problem to change decimal format number. If I using `$(selector).inputmask({ 'alias': 'decimal', 'groupSeparator': '.', 'autoGroup': true, 'rightAlign': false });` the decimal result is `10,000.00`. How to change to format `10.000,00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [radixPoint](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/#radixpoint-numerics) to `,` and [groupSeparator](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/#groupseparator-numerics) to `.`.

```
$(selector).inputmask({
    'alias': 'decimal',
    'radixPoint': ',',
    'groupSeparator': '.',
    'autoGroup': true,
    'rightAlign': false,
    'numericInput': true
});
```

Please also check this example: http://codepen.io/rooyva/pen/1f20a3883258d306b5098f03ab30517f/